# Create a typing only for some properties of an object

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to only specify the type for some properties of an object instead of all? For example, if I have some object like

```js
const user_account = {id: 37593, created: "23/04/2020", last_active: "23/04/2020"};
```

and I only wanted to specify `id` to be of type `number`, and everything else kept as `any`, is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Like `const settings: { id: number, [k: string]: any } = {id: 37593, created: "23/04/2020", last_active: "23/04/2020"};` (that is, use an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types))? Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @jcalz That works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a  [string index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) to represent that all the properties conform to a particular value type; in your case, `any`.  Any named properties you add to the object outside the index signature must still conform to that type, but you can make them more specific.  Since `number` is more specific than `any`, you can represent your type like `{ [k: string]: any; id: number }`.

So

```
const settings: { id: number, [k: string]: any } = 
  {id: 37593, created: "23/04/2020", last_active: "23/04/2020"};
```

should work for you, depending on your use case.  Note that such an annotation will widen the type of `settings` to the annotated type, so the compiler will not remember anything not specified in that type:

```
settings.id; // known to be number
settings.created; // only known as any, not string
settings.randomPropName; // also known as any
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUoEswHMIC4YG8bIBNswBXAWwCN4AnAGhgG0Brbaa1NAXWwEMwBPGAF8YAXgCwAKBgzc+IjADMAdgCsATkX1g1eDyjwFAIgBMigPQAGACzmTl+0foAbHtAD6PYCgBu8bKYWNnYOlkbCANxSUghIHBAAdIQRMObmMExgIADuYDBQIDBUMKSUNDGIKOiJOnoGBClpMODOgpk5eW4wfPz0WbBsHBVx1QnUfAQgZAAK1CAADgByPGTwjek8zhCF7bndEN0CMEA)